Отображение годов в DateEdit devexpress MAUI
Когда выбираешь год последние два года имеют стиль будто они не активны, но доступны к выбору.
Вижу, что это связано, что выбирается десятилетие, и поэтому два последние года выделены как неактивные.
Есть свойство, но оно мне не подходит, потому что задают стиль всем неактивным годам также меняет стиль и последних двух годов, которые активны к выбору
<dxe:DateEdit.PickerYearCellAppearance>
     <dxe:CalendarYearCellAppearance DisabledTextColor="Black" TextColor="Red" />
 </dxe:DateEdit.PickerYearCellAppearance>

Код:
xmlns:editors="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Editors;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Editors"
<editors:DateEdit
    Margin="0,0,0,10"
    Date="{Binding BirthDate.Value}"
    LabelText="Дата рождения"
    MaxDate="{Binding BirthDate.MaxValue}"
    PlaceholderText="Дата рождения">
</editors:DateEdit>


Как исправить?
